# Minimum velocity needed to pass between two moving circles

Tags: calculus, optimization

Suppose we have two circles with radius $r$ whose circumferences are $d$ metres apart from each other and are each moving in the same straight line at a velocity of $u$ metres per second.

What is the minimum velocity $v$ needed for a point to pass between the two circles perpendicular to the circles' direction of travel?

I may not have explained this well, so [here is a desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sf3atsnzpd) that I made to replicate the situation - I fiddled around with the variables until the point passes almost perfectly through.

I have been stuck on this question for quite a while with zero progress and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible approach: shift your frame of reference. Imagine that the circles are not moving, and instead that the point is moving *diagonally* toward them. The minimum velocity for the point corresponds to the most acute possible angle of this diagonal approach, and this is achieved when the path of the point is tangent to both circles. If you can figure out what this common interior tangent line is, everything else should follow.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Given, $OP=EF=MN=d$ and $OM=NP=2r$
Consider circles to be stationary. Point needs to move from N to O to not collide with circles. It has relative speed of $u$ towards left. It has speed of $v$ towards top.
Time taken to cross horizontal length $=\dfrac{d}{u}$
Distance moved vertically in same time $=\dfrac{vd}{u}$
Now for minimum speed, $$2r=\dfrac{vd}{u}$$ $$v=\dfrac{2ru}{d}$$

Comment: The path from N to O would not give the minimum velocity. I suggest you read the comment by @C J Dowd